# How to set another app focus and make it active window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a winform VS 2013 C# windows application. I have a small window that is 'Top Most' and sits on top of a flight simulator (FSX) app running in windowed mode.

I want to click a button on my small app form and then have the FSX app take the focus again so I can use my FSX hot keys to do stuff inside FSX while flying.

When FSX is running the sound is enabled so I can hear it when it has the focus.

When I click a button my small app form, I don't hear the sound about 50% of the time. So, FSX is getting the focus about half the time I click a button on my small app and half the time it doesn't get the focus.

My code is below. Is there a better way, more reliable way, to do this?

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("fsx");
        if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
            {
                SwitchToThisWindow(p.Handle, true);
                p.Refresh();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't hear the sound about 50% of the time

Short answer - FSX (out of the box) **does not** play sound when it is in the background.

So when your app has focus, FSX sounds will stop sadly.

To fix it your `SwitchToThisWindow()` would need to perform the equivalent of sending **WM_ACTIVATE** to FSX when you wish to re-activate FSX.  You seem to be doing this much already as evidenced by your 50% success rate - that it would seem to imply there is a deeper issue.

> So, FSX is getting the focus about half the time I click a button on my small app and half the time it doesn't get the focus.

You may want to **delay** sending the activation and **not** send it during the button click event due to your button click is also involved in a prior focus event.  Consider using a *one-off timer* or *STA dispatcher* to set FSX focus **at some time in the future** (perhaps 10 ms) **after** you have finished processing your click event.

The reason I say this is that your app is marked as **WS_EX_TOPMOST** which may lead to some whacky *circular loop* or *bounce*.

### Sources

- http://www.avsim.com/topic/421600-window-focus-and-sound/
- http://steamcommunity.com/app/314160/discussions/1/620712999984244237/

Comment: @user337447 Post your code for `SwitchToThisWindow()`